# C++ iostream read with delimiter of MULTIPLE bytes

Tags: c++, iostream

We know to read from an input stream, we can use the below standard C++ function

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

However we can only provide delimiter of one byte/char.

How should I do if I wish to use delimiter with multiple bytes?
Is there any neat stuff I can leverage, boost?

Bests,
Lyn

Comment: Boost Spirit would be one possibility.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes. But only if you have the time.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, @MarkGarcia, thanks for your words! Could you please give a simple sample of using it? I`m not quite famiilar with it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `cin.get()` instead of `cin.getline()`. Read one character each time and test whether the delimiter occurs.

int main(void){

```
string str;  
int length_of_delimiter = 3;  
const char *delimiter = "ABC";  
char temp = '0';  
bool over = false;  
cout<<"Enter the stream"<<endl;

temp =  cin.get();
int  i = 0;
while(over == false){ 
        for(i = 0; temp  == delimiter[i] && i < length_of_delimiter; i++){
            str += temp;
            temp = cin.get();
        }
        if(i == length_of_delimiter){
            //chop off the delimiter
            str.erase(str.end() - length_of_delimiter, str.end());
            over = true;
        }
        else {
            str += temp;
            temp = cin.get();
        }
}
cout<<"The stream we wanted is: "<<str<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: you need to check if there is data before each read, with `cin.good()` for instance.

Comment: I agree with you, this is my final solution.